How to create file in AWS codecommit?
I am creating a project. This project will log payment details when a payment is created.
import * as fs from 'fs/promises';
import * as path from 'path';
app.use('/files', async (req, res) => {
  const filePath = path.join(
    `log-files/test_${moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')}.txt`
  );

  const value = 'TEST FILE CREATION IN AWS';

  try {
    await fs.readFile(filePath);

    await fs.appendFile(filePath, `\n\n${value}`);
    res.status(200).send(`File created in, ${filePath}`);
  } catch (error) {
    await fs.writeFile(filePath, value);
    console.log(error);
    res.status(200).send(`File created in, ${filePath}`);
  }
});

The above is the code I tried.
This is my script to create the file. It works well in local, but when in AWS CodeCommit,
the API calling is success and log with File created in, log-files/test_2024-09-30.txt
But when I check in log-files folder under the repo, it doesn't have this file.

I don't know CodeCommit but if it's a git repo I'd guess you'd need to 1) create the file and then 2) create a commit containing the file. I'd expect the appendFile or writeFile to return you a filesystem state token to pass to a commit API. What do you get back from those methods? And if it was me I'd change the response body so I knew if it was the append or write paths that got taken too.

@Rup From the log I could know that the file is created which is under catch error, but the returned value from appendFile is undefined File created in log-files/test_2024-09-30.txt undefined. About the first method you mention, I think it is not suitable for my project, because the file will be created when payment is created and I cant control when the payment is created.

If I call this API for the second times, the response is changed which means the file exist, but I can find the file under the folder in my repo

OK, I think you'll still need to call something else to commit the changes but I'd guess my temporary filesystem state is stored in your session. Why are you saving payment data in code commit though? There must be somewhere better e.g. a database?

Ok thanks.
I am saving the data because it is only a log record the id, status, message of success/failed, timestamp. But your are right, maybe I should store in db. Thanks !
